# Does javascript still execute if I navigate to a different page?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a set-up like this:

```
$('#mylink').click(function(event){
   savePost();
});

<a id="mylink" href="http://google.com">my link</a>
```

If I click the link will I be gone to a different page without giving the function a chance to execute?

What if savePost() has ajax and a callback function? Will it execute regardless of what page the browser is on when the script executes? (or would I have to preventDefault on the link and put the window.location command within the callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

onclick script will be executed before changing window.location

on ajax callback, i don't think so, as ajax and callback are asynchronous calls,
so if you need to navigate only after success perform of ajax call use `complete(jqXHR, textStatus)` callback on `jQuery.ajax()` together with `preventDefault()`

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I don't have much experience with jQuery, but how about using `jQuery.ajax( url, {async: false} );` ?

Comment: `async: false` is something you should never use, this is the rule.

Answer (score 2):

Script will be executed first, then window.location

Answer (score 1):

Call `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the link from actually changing the page. Otherwise the page will change after the onclick function has been executed.